# how to pass multiple values for WHERE clause as single argument

Tags: mysql, select, sqlanywhere

I am looking to update data of my table based on the query result.

The database structure is as follows.

Table name - ***Customer***

```
id | user_id | key | value
```

sample data is as follows:

```
1 | 3434 | first_name | Brandon
2 | 3434 | last_name  | Johnson
3 | 3434 | street_add | 123 main
4 | 3434 | city       | ocean beach
5 | 3434 | state      | Texas
```

My query is to update value result based on my condition.

```
UPDATE Customer
   SET key='abcd', value='efghg'
 WHERE id =2,4,5;
```

***the error that I get is  could not prepare statement (1 near ",": syntax error)***

Here I want to pass multiple values for id and say what ever the values that I pass those results need to be updated like below.
So the output table that should look like below

Expected O/P

```
id | user_id | key | value

1 | 3434 | first_name | Brandon 
2 | 3434 | abcd       | efghg 
3 | 3434 | street_add | 123 main 
4 | 3434 | abcd       | efghg 
5 | 3434 | abcd       | efghg
```

How to pass multiple values for a WHERE condition.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Where clause support IN to support multiple values

```
UPDATE Customer SET key='abcd', value='efghg' WHERE id IN (2,4,5)
```